# How to get the text input by user in ion searchbar

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic4

I am creating an app and I want to get the text the user entered into the search bar after hitting enter and assign that value to a variable. All the examples I have come across only shows list filtering and I am still stuck. I am trying to do this on a one-line code.

```
<ion-searchbar placeholder="Search" type="text" id="term" ></ion-searchbar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing much to do, try

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ionInput)="searchEventFired()"></ion-searchbar>
```

to work with `enter` you need to do:

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (keydown.enter)="searchEventFired()"></ion-searchbar>
```

**OR**

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (search)="searchEventFired()"></ion-searchbar>
```

In  **component.ts**

```
searchTerm = '';

constructor(){}

searchEventFired() {
  // you have the value here
  console.log(this.searchTerm)
}
```

[demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic3-search-bar-sample-p2g2pg?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Comment: In VScode, i am told that searchTerm is not defined so i set 'searchTerm' as a string instead and it now works but it keeps saving the text even when the user hasnt hit enter. @Shashank Vivek

Comment: At first the code above didnt work for me so I used ```(keydown.enter)="searchInput()"``` to replace ```(search)``` and it works fine now.

Comment: @DreadedHippy: Thanks for the edit. But I was able to run it with `search` , you can check the demo code. May be there is some version mismatch. Anyways I think it can be marked as answer

Comment: @DreadedHippy There is one more option I personally prefer. <ion-searchbar  [formControl]="searchControl"></ion-searchbar> and then you can subscribe to the changes on FormControl:  this.searchControl.valueChanges.pipe(...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that search components is your own components not provided by external library.

You can have one keydown event listener and pass event as parameter to the function at your html. Inside that function check for keys pressed and match with keys you wanna check for it.